# Delete[] is not calling elements destructors

Tags: c++, arrays, destructor, trie

I've started to implement a dictionary using a *trie*. Basically, i have a root node which has a definition (pointer to `T` that represents de value associated to the key) and childs (pointer to array that contains pointers to 256 nodes, one for each letter). check the definitions out:

```
template<typename T>
class DiccString {
        public:
                DiccString() : root(NULL);
                DiccString(const DiccString<T>&);
                ~DiccString() {delete root;}

                void define(const string& key, const T& value);
                bool isDefined(const string& key) const;
                const T& getDefinition(const string& key) const;
                T& getDefinition(const string& key);
                void remove(const string& key);
                const Set<string>& keys() const;

        private:

                struct Node{
                    Node** childs;
                    T* definition;
                    Node(){
                        std::cout << "Node has been created " << this << std::endl;
                        childs = new Node*[256];
                        definition = NULL;
                    }
                    ~Node(){
                        std::cout << "Node has been deleted " << this << std::endl;
                        delete definition;
                        delete [] childs;
                    }
                };

                Node* root;
};
```

So if i want to store "*John*" with the value *14* (`T` would be `int` so), assuming there is no other key, then i would create a root, then at root->`childs[(int)'j']` i would create another node "nodeJ", and then nodeJ->`childs[(int)'o']`, and so on until reaching the last node "nodeN", which will contain the value (`nodeN->definition = 14`).

The problem is when i do:

```
int main() {
    DiccString<int> d;
    d.define("john",20);
    d.define("jane",25);

    return 0;
}
```

Then i expect all nodes created to be destroyed but take a look at the output:

```
Node created 0x61fc20 // root
Node created 0x620860 // for letter 'j'
Node created 0x621090 // for letter 'o' (child of 'j' 0x620860)
Node created 0x6218c0 // for letter 'h' (child of 'o' 0x621090)
Node created 0x6220f0 // for letter 'n' (child of 'h' 0x6218c0), value: 20
Node created 0x622990 // for letter 'a' (child of 'j' 0x620860)
Node created 0x6231c0 // for letter 'n' (child of 'a' 0x622990)
Node created 0x6239f0 // for letter 'e' (child of 'n' 0x6231c0), value: 25
Node deleted 0x61fc20 // root
```

Just the root is being deleted. So apparently when it comes to execute `delete [] childs` in the destructor of `Node`, it's not deleting all the elements of the array, which i'm sure that exist: for instance, in the case of the call to the destructor of root (which is the only one actually being called), i evaluated `childs[(int)'j']` and it's certainly 0x620860, so i know it should call the destructor of this element (at least) when it executes `delete [] childs`, right?

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`childs` has type `Node**`, it is a pointer to a pointer. You allocate for it an array of `Node*` pointers.

`delete[] childs` deletes this allocation, i.e. only the memory for the pointers, not the objects the pointers point to.

We don't see the code where you actually allocate `Node`s, but you must store somewhere somehow which of the 256 allocated `Node*` actually point to a valid `Node` object. Maybe you do it via marking the pointers with a NULL pointer? In that case you probably want to do something like:

```
for(int i=0; i<256; ++i) {
    delete childs[i];
}
```

I should also note, that you should use a static array if the number of Node pointers is fixed and an `std::vector` otherwise.

Comment: Ohhhh i see.. i'll try to solve it tomorrow. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

The printout only occurs for destruction of `Node` objects but not `Node *`.  You can check that the behavior is correct by using a debugger.

Note that instead of lazily allocating in `define()` it might be clearer if you had symmetry among the constructor/destructor.  Also be sure to handle correctly the case when `DiccString` is empty when deallocated.

Comment: What do you mean by having simmetry between constructor and destructor? (Thanks for answering btw)

Comment: `DiccString()` should have allocations and `~DiccString()` should have matching deallocations.